# LESS compiles border-radius: 50% / 20%

Tags: css, less

I have this line in my less file.

```
 border-radius: 50% / 20%;
```

LESS compiles this line to:

```
 border-radius: 2.5%;
```

How to force Less not to compile this line?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Opt #1: By Strict-Math

The `strict-math` setting affects this. Turning it on then requires all math to be inside parenthesis; see [the change documentation for LESS 1.4](http://lesscss.org/#changes)), so LESS would not do its own math operation (division here) if turned on because your values are not inside parentheses.

### Opt #2: By String Interpolation

Input it as an escaped string value like so:

```
border-radius: ~"50% / 20%";
```

This avoids the math being done as well, because the values are being given as a string, but the output itself cannot be a string (as in have the quote marks), so we escape it to make it the raw input of `50% / 20%` without the quotes.